# Tables not styled properly

Tags: html

I'm new to html and I'm trying to create tables and style them but they are not styled as I'd like: http://jsfiddle.net/DpLy5/

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Tabeller</title>
        <style>
            body{
                padding-top: 20px;
                padding-left: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 700px; height:150px; border: 1px solid black;">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/700x150">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 150px; height:700px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #808080;">adad</td>
                <td style="width: 400px; height:700px; border: 1px solid black;">adad</td>
                <td style="width: 150px; height:700px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #808080;">adad</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 700px; height:75px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #808080;"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The middle row first column should be 150px wide but its bigger then that. I don't know what it could be. Any help? Thank you

Comment: Your first column in the second row has a width of 700px. So the first column has a width of 700px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a colspan='3' on your first and third row tr. As you have it set to 700px and it's a single column it will push the one above/below it to the same:

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebean/DpLy5/1/

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 700px; height:150px; border: 1px solid black;" colspan='3'>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/700x150">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 150px; height:700px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #808080;">adad</td>
        <td style="width: 400px; height:700px; border: 1px solid black;">adad</td>
        <td style="width: 150px; height:700px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #808080;">adad</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 700px; height:75px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #808080;" colspan='3'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also, I highly suggest using non-inline styling as it will make it a lot easier to see what you are doing and separate style from content.

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebean/DpLy5/8/

```
<table class='myTable'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan='3'>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/700x150" />
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>adad</td>
            <td class='main'>adad</td>
            <td>adad</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='3'></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>    
</table>
```

css:

```
.myTable {
    width: 700px; 
}

.myTable td, .myTable th {
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.myTable thead th {
    height:150px;  
}

.myTable tbody td {
    width: 150px; 
    height:700px; 
    background-color: #808080;
}    

.myTable tbody td.main {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.myTable tfoot td {
    height:75px;
    background-color: #808080;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the `td` in the first `tr` span the three columns using `colspan="3"` similar to the `td` in the last `tr`.

```
<td colspan="3" style="width: 700px; height:150px; border: 1px solid black;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/700x150">
</td>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/DpLy5/3/

Answer (score 1):

you will need to add **colspan="3"** to  in first row & last row... that's it.

http://jsfiddle.net/DpLy5/6/

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="width: 700px; height:150px; border: 1px solid black;">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/700x150">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 150px; height:700px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #808080;">adad</td>
        <td style="width: 400px; height:700px; border: 1px solid black;">adad</td>
        <td style="width: 150px; height:700px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #808080;">adad</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="width: 700px; height:75px; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #808080;"></td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in need of the `colspan` attribute. The `colspan` attribute in fact says "Let me span this amount of column in the table".

Which means `colspan="3`" is translated to "Let me span 3 columns in the table"

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_span

However, according to your JSFiddle, you are trying to make a raster for your layout. Achieving this with the use of `table`'s is a no-go, it's a major bad practice.

This is because a table is something where you put data in, and an entire layout is not data.

The best way to set up and layout is using Div's. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp